# how to make vowel counter and sum more concise and efficient? Python

Tags: python, optimization

I am new to Stack Overflow, but noticed how helpful, and open this community is. Just curious if there is anyway to make this vowel counter more concise/organized. Any help would be appreciated, and an in-depth answer would be awesome as well. Thank you!

```
def vowel_count(str):

    str = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
    str1 = (str.lower())
    #intialize count variable to zero
    count = 0

    #create a set of vowels
    vowel = set("aeiou")

    for alphabet in str1:
        if alphabet in vowel:
            count = count+1

    print("Number of vowels in this sentence is: " , count)
    print()
    print("A,E,I,O,U")
    print(*map(str.lower().count, "aeiou"))

vowel_count(str)
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [codereview.se]? Stack Overflow is for definite questions, not open questions. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a simple dict-map for it: `{v: sentence.count(v) for v in 'aeiou'}` (lowercase your sentence first, of course). That way you can access individual count for each vowel or get a total amount of vowels by simply summing the `dict` values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that in your code example, you used a variable named str. Don't do that, as str is a built-in function and this can lead to problems.

What about this solution:

```
string = input().lower()

print(sum([string.count(i) for i in "aeiou"]))
```

Firstly, I get the input, which I lower immediately.
Then, I used the string.count(i) for every vowel, which in this case returns the amount of times i (one of the vowels) appears in the string (input).
I then called the sum function on the created array which returns the sum of all elements inside the array. Last but not least, I simply printed the value returned from this sum function.

If you don't understand how the argument passed to the sum function is an array, look into the topic of [List Comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-list-comprehension).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter
In [1]: a = 'I am mayank'
In [5]: ans = Counter(a.lower())

In [6]: ans
Out[6]: Counter({' ': 2, 'a': 3, 'i': 1, 'k': 1, 'm': 2, 'n': 1, 'y': 1})

In [10]: ans['a']
Out[10]: 3
```

This will count the occurrence of each letter in the string including vowels. This should be quite efficient.